# ErrorException in LoginController.php line 31: Non-static method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::attempt() should not be called statically

Tags: laravel

When I write web service for Admin login, I faced this problem:

> ErrorException in LoginController.php line 31: Non-static method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::attempt() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

My login controller code is below:

```
public function adminLogin()
{
    $auth =  Auth::guard(AppParams::AUTH_ADMIN);
    if ($auth::attempt(array('am_email' => Input::get('am_email'), 'am_password' => Input::get('am_password')))) {
        return response()->json(array('login_status' => 'success', 'adminID' => $auth->user()->am_id));
    } else {
        return response()->json(array('login_status' => 'not found'));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$auth::attempt` to `$auth->attempt`. Should fix your problem.

Comment: Good to hear! If you like to help others when they have the same problem, select this answer as the selected answer, so it shows up in google!

Answer (score 0):

Call it like this:

```
$auth->attempt(
```